# Arc SVG Parameters

Tags: javascript, python, svg, plotly, trigonometry

I've been trying to understand arc svg since it seems I need them in plotly -- my goal is to plot circle intersections.

My original idea was something like this:

[image]

for every intersection, to find the start and end coordinates as well as the height - but I am not very sure of where to go from here. It seems I am lacking the rotation and Large Arc Flag / Sweep parameters, and I am not sure how I would go about retrieving them. If anyone could point me into the right direction here, that would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Circles and intercepting points

MDN gives `"A rx,ry xAxisRotate LargeArcFlag,SweepFlag x,y"` as an arc in the path element. What are `rx` and `ry`? I would guess radius for x,y.

I am guessing you would use it as

```
// x,y start position
// rx,ry radius x and y
// x1,y1 end position
<path d="M x,y A rx, ry, 0 1 1 x1, y1"/>
```

Below is the problem solved as javascript. I have Commented the part you need for the SVG. The two end points (intercepts)

There is a lot of redundancy but its not clear what you want so the code provides how to find other parts of two intersecting circles.

### Law of Cosines

The math to solve the problem is called the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) that is used to solve triangles.

In this case the triangle is created from 3 lengths. One each of the circle radius and one is the distance between circle centers. The image gives more details

[image]

With the angle c you can find the lengths GE, DE, and EF. If you want the angle for the other side at point f just swap B and C.

### Example

Move mouse to check intercept.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const m = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  var b = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  m.x = e.pageX - b.left - scrollX;
  m.y = e.pageY - b.top - scrollY;
});
const PI = Math.PI;
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
const circles = [];

function circle(x, y, r, col, f = 0, t = PI2, w = 2) {
  var c;
  circles.push(c = { x, y,r, col, f, t, w});
  return c;
};

function drawCircle(A) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = A.col;
  ctx.lineWidth = A.w;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(A.x, A.y, A.r, A.f, A.t);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function mark(x, y, r, c) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = c;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, PI2);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function line(A, B, c) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = c;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(A.x, A.y);
  ctx.lineTo(B.x, B.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// note I am sharing calc results between function  


function circleIntercept(A, B) {
  var vx, vy, dist, c, d, x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2, dir, a1, a2;
  // Vec from A to B
  vx = B.x - A.x;
  vy = B.y - A.y;
  // Distance between
  dist = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
  // Are the intercepting
  if (dist < A.r + B.r && dist > B.r - A.r) {
    c = (B.r * B.r - (dist * dist + A.r * A.r)) / (-2 * dist);

    // Find mid point on cord
    x = A.x + vx * (c / dist);
    y = A.y + vy * (c / dist);
    mark(x, y, 5, "blue");

    // Find circumference intercepts

    //#################################################################
    //=================================================================
    // SVG path 
    // Use x1,y1 and x2,y2 as the start and end angles of the ArcTo SVG
    d = Math.sqrt(A.r * A.r - c * c);
    x1 = x - vy * (d / dist);
    y1 = y + vx * (d / dist);
    x2 = x + vy * (d / dist);
    y2 = y - vx * (d / dist);
    // SVG path from above coords
    // d = `M ${x1}, ${y1} A ${A.r}, ${A,r1} 0, 1, 1, ${x2}, ${y2}`;
    //=================================================================

    // draw the chord
    line({x: x1,y: y1}, {x: x2,y: y2}, "red");
    
    // mark the intercepts
    mark(x1, y1, 5, "Green");
    mark(x2, y2, 5, "Orange");

    // Get direction from A to B
    dir = Math.atan2(vy, vx);

    // Get half inside sweep
    a1 = Math.acos(c / A.r);

    // Draw arc for A
    A.col = "black";
    A.w = 4;
    A.f = dir - a1;
    A.t = dir + a1;
    drawCircle(A);
    A.col = "#aaa";
    A.w = 2;
    A.f = 0;
    A.t = PI2;

    // inside sweep for B
    a2 = Math.asin(d / B.r);

    // Draw arc for B
    B.col = "black";
    B.w = 4;
    if (dist < c) {
      B.t = dir - a2;
      B.f = dir + a2;
    } else {

      B.f = dir + PI - a2;
      B.t = dir + PI + a2;
    }
    drawCircle(B);
    B.col = "#aaa";
    B.w = 2;
    B.f = 0;
    B.t = PI2;

  }

}

var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2; // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var C1 = circle(cw, ch, ch * 0.5, "#aaa");
var C2 = circle(cw, ch, ch * 0.8, "#aaa");

function update(timer) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
    cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
    C1.x = cw;
    C1.y = ch;
    C1.r = ch * 0.5;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
  }
  C2.x = m.x;
  C2.y = m.y;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);


  drawCircle(C1);
  drawCircle(C2);
  circleIntercept(C1, C2);






  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It took some time for me to work through this :) I wish I could give you more upvotes for it! Probably I should learn and do my project in JS, rather than transforming my results to SVG from Python. Thanks!!

Comment: @erocoar In all the typing I forgot to add the most important part. All the maths is based on Law of cosines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Law_of_cosines That provide an easy way to solve any triangle if you have any 3 of a triangles 6 properties (3 side lengths and 3  angles) The circle intercepts is a solution to a triangle with sides A,B,C where A is the dist between circle centers, and B, and C are the radius of the two circles.The angle `acos((C*C-(A*A+B*B))/(-2*A*B))` is the angle from joining line between to the intercept.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with some terminology to clear up what is a clockwise direction (remember the y axis of SVG goes *down*): the first circle has radius `r1`, the second `r2`.

- If the center of the first circle is lower than that of the second (`cy1 > cy2`), then name the intersection point with the smaller x coordinate `(x1, y1)`, and the other `(x2, y2)`.
- If the center of the first circle is higher than that of the second (`cy1 < cy2`), then name the intersection point with the greater x coordinate `(x1, y1)`, and the other `(x2, y2)`.
- Else, name the intersection point with the smaller y coordinate `(x1, y1)`, and the other `(x2, y2)`.

Now we will draw an arc from the first to the second intersection point with the radius of the first circle. The first two arc parameters are the horizontal and vertical radius. Since we are drawing a circle, both are identical. For the same reason, rotating the radii does not make sense and the third parameter is 0.

The intersection of two circles always uses the small arc (the large arc would be used for the union), therefore the large arc flag is 0. We are drawing the arc clockwise, therefore the sweep flag is 1.

Still unclear? The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) uses this picture for explaining the flags:

[image]

The second arc is going from the second to the first intersection point with the radius of the second circle. The flags remain the same.

The result looks like this:

```
M x1, y1 A r1 r1 0 0 1 x2, y2 A r2 r2 0 0 1 x1, y1 Z
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful - I guess I went wrong with treating the intersection as part of a new ellipse. :) For defining which circle is left/right, would I do it by angle?

Comment: It is more a question of how you order the intersection points. You could also say: draw an arrow from circle1 to circle2, and go from the intersection point to the left of the arrow to the point on the right with radius1, and back with radius 2. It all depends on your code.

Comment: Maybe this is even easier: if cy of circle1 is greater than cy of circle2, then start at the intersection point that has the smaller x coordinate. If the cy are equal, start at  the intersection point with the smaller y.